# How to connect Simulink to GDB Server and then Segger J-Link via USB

Tags: matlab, gdb, simulink

I have the Energy Micro EFM32 ARM dev board (EFM32LG-DK3650) that I am trying to connect to with Simulink/GDB Server. The GDB Server connects just fine to the EFM board. It appears that Simulink will not talk to the GDB Server. Has anyone tried connecting Simulink to the GDB Server and had success...**other than using any Board Support Packages**?

I am using External Mode set in the two places required.

**This is the error I receive from Simulink:**

*Error occurred while executing External Mode MEX-file 'ext_serial_win32_comm': Failed to connect to the target. A time-out occurred while waiting for the first connect response packet. Possible reasons for the time-out: a) The target is not switched on. b) The target is not connected to your host machine. c) The application for the model is not running on the target. You might have clicked the Stop button.
Component: Simulink | Category: Model error*

I have been searching for days and reading everything in sight. It appears either that no one else has done this, or had this problem.

Thanks for any help.